# customize json response from WCF Rest service

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest

I've created a WCF Rest service that reads google APIs json data and sends a jsonp response back to another application. I have a class that returns a list collection of another class and one integer member called total.

My jsonp format is like:

```
   jsonCallback({"results":["list" : {"title":"Pulkit Gulati", "htmlSnippet" : "..."}, 
                                     {"title":"Pulkit Gulati", "htmlSnippet" : "..."}
                           ],
                 _total=50}
   );

[DataContract]
public class GResult
{
    [DataMember(Order=2)]
    public string htmlSnippet { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order=1)]
    public string title { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class GResultPadding
{
    [DataMember(Order=1)]
    public IEnumerable<GResult> list { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order=2)]
    public int _total { get; set; }
}
```

I want the output response as below, "list" removed:

```
jsonCallback({"results":[{"title":"Pulkit Gulati", "htmlSnippet" : "..."}, 
                                     {"title":"Pulkit Gulati", "htmlSnippet" : "..."}
                           ],
                 _total=50}
   );
```

My method returns:

```
GResultPadding getDataFromGoogle(string firstName, string lastName);
```

Is there a way that I can remove the key "list" from this response and keep the collection without this? The rest of the formed result is fine. I'm using body style as Wrapped and WebGet for the method.

Comment: Are you saying that you want Results to be an array of dictionaries? The easiest way would be to change your DTO to reflect that

Comment: Edited the post... please let me know if it explains the problem better...

Comment: Unless there's something missing from the Json snippet, the DTOs and the snippet do not match. Where does `results` come from and why is `_total` defined outside it? Try capturing the actual Json using Fiddler

Comment: results come after using this on the method... [return: MessageParameter(Name = "results")]

Comment: and _total is the total number of results in the collection with title and htmlSnippet... so that is kept outside with the help of a wrapper class GResultPadding...